# UITableView scroll to bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have this line of code:

```
tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10000000.0f);
```

The content size is a lot less than the `10000000.0f`, but the UITableView still does not scroll to the bottom. How can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scrolling to `tableViewCell`?

```
//for instance, you have 15 cells
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:14 inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                              animated:YES];
```

Comment: It doesn't need `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 9):

### Swift 5, iOS 12 tested

#### This code works perfectly for `UITableView`, even if there are sections with 0 elements (which will crash in every other solution I saw on the Internet)

```
extension UITableView {
    func scrollTableViewToBottom(animated: Bool) {
        guard let dataSource = dataSource else { return }

        var lastSectionWithAtLeasOneElements = (dataSource.numberOfSections?(in: self) ?? 1) - 1

        while dataSource.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: lastSectionWithAtLeasOneElements) < 1 {
            lastSectionWithAtLeasOneElements -= 1
        }

        let lastRow = dataSource.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: lastSectionWithAtLeasOneElements) - 1

        guard lastSectionWithAtLeasOneElements > -1 && lastRow > -1 else { return }

        let bottomIndex = IndexPath(item: lastRow, section: lastSectionWithAtLeasOneElements)
        scrollToRow(at: bottomIndex, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

**fixed version from Kevin in this topic, preventing infinite scroll for tableView with `0` items:**
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59470799/9763761

```
func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
    guard let dataSource = dataSource else { return }
    var lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement = (dataSource.numberOfSections?(in: self) ?? 1) - 1
    while dataSource.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement) < 1 && lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement > 0 {
        lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement -= 1
    }
    let lastRow = dataSource.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement) - 1
    guard lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement > -1 && lastRow > -1 else { return }
    let bottomIndex = IndexPath(item: lastRow, section: lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement)
    scrollToRow(at: bottomIndex, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
}
```

#### This code works for `UIScrollView`, but won't work for `UITableView` that have more cells then one screen can fit, because of Apple's weird internal implementation of `UITableViewController`:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
        guard contentSize.height > bounds.size.height else { return }

        let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentSize.height - bounds.size.height + contentInset.bottom)
        setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create an extension of `UIScrollView`, and use it for any instance of UIScrollView, UITableView or UICollectionView.

```
extension UIScrollView {

    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
        var y: CGFloat = 0.0
        let HEIGHT = self.frame.size.height
        if self.contentSize.height > HEIGHT {
            y = self.contentSize.height - HEIGHT
        }
        self.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, y), animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Whenever the content size if greater than scroll view's height, it will scroll accordingly to the correct position. This method works with AutoLayout also.

Comment: +1 - This is a good answer. Consider making the extension not on UITableView, but on UIScrollView, that way it works for all UIScrollView subclasses (like normal UIScrollView, UITableView and UICollectionView). Another small improvement could be this: try not to use the SCREEN_HEIGHT, but replace this by the height of the UIScrollView, because the scrollview might not cover the whole screen (and thus is less height).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I don't yet have enough rep to comment, but vol's answer has 1 mistake in it which causes an infinite while loop when you call it on a tableview with 0 items, aside from that it works perfectly! Corrected code below:

```
func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
    guard let dataSource = dataSource else { return }
    var lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement = (dataSource.numberOfSections?(in: self) ?? 1) - 1
    while dataSource.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement) < 1 && lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement > 0 {
        lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement -= 1
    }
    let lastRow = dataSource.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement) - 1
    guard lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement > -1 && lastRow > -1 else { return }
    let bottomIndex = IndexPath(item: lastRow, section: lastSectionWithAtLeastOneElement)
    scrollToRow(at: bottomIndex, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: I've added your fix to my solution as well, sourcing to this post :) Hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()+0.1, execute: {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.dateSource.count-1, section: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
})
```