# SwiftUI: ContextMenu flipping bug?

Tags: swiftui

I am implementing a chat in SwiftUI. I am using a double rotated list to show the most recent chat messages on the bottom. Each message has a context menu attached. But there is bug: when tapping on the context menu, the message does an erroneous rotation animation. It looks bad. Using XCode 12.2.

Any ideas how to get this working? I did file a bug report with Apple, but that typically takes months (years?).

Here is basic example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FlippedContextMenuBug: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                Text("Message \(i)")
                    .padding()
                    .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                        Text("Menu Item 1")
                    })
                    .rotationEffect(.pi)
            }
        }
        .rotationEffect(.pi)
    }
}

struct FlippedContextMenuBug_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FlippedContextMenuBug()
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Is this the code to reproduce issue? Could you attach gif with recorded effect?

Comment: It was working fine on XCode 12.1. But 12.2 broke it.

Comment: @Arman I'm assuming no solutions a year later?

Comment: Well I found your older question which looks useful, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61726424/9607863)

Comment: Still happen in xcode 14.2