# SwiftUI ScrollView does not respond to keyboard

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-list

Thanks for taking your time to help others :)

### Problem description:

I want to bring up the ScrollView content as keyboard shows up. And I can't.

Despite, if ScrollView is turned upside down... it works!!! But I can't do that because I have to implement .contextMenu(...) and this produces an even worse bug ([detailed in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75213143/reverse-scrollview-bug-in-ios-15-contextmenu)).

**App must support iOS 14.**

### Simple code demo to show what happens.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView() {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(1..<201, id: \.self) { num in
                        Text("Message \(num)")
                    }
//                    .upsideDown() // With these modifiers, will prompt up the scrollView content
                }
            }
//            .upsideDown() // With these modifiers, will prompt up the scrollView content
            
            TextField("Your text here", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .padding()
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationTitle("Example app")
    }
}

extension View {
    func upsideDown() -> some View {
        self.rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
    }
}
```

### GIF resources to see behaviour:

1. Good result (when upside down):
   [image: Good result (when upside down)]
2. Bad result (on normal scrollView):
   [image: Bad result (on normal scrollView)]

### What we have checked?

Already tried [this solution](https://www.vbutko.com/articles/how-to-manage-swiftui-focus-state-in-ios14-and-before/), but does not help.

Tried setting an offset to ScrollView of keyboards height when it does come up but... nothing happens.

### Questions

1. Why does this happen when it is upside down? (and not at normal scrollview)
2. Why on both cases it brings up the TextField but does NOT bring up the content of Scrollview if is not upside down???